# setting a page as "Page Post" gives me a "Not Found" message

Tags: wordpress

I created 2 pages.  let's say "Page 1" and "Page 2". When I view the website, both pages display just fine.

Then I:

1. go to Settings -> Reading
2. select "A Static Page"
3. I set "Page 1" as Front Page  & "Page 2" as the Post Page.

I refresh my site and I get a "Not Found" message when I click on Page 2 on the nav bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have at least one post (not a page) in your blog?

Comment: initially i didn't. But upon reading your comment i made a post and it worked.  I don't know why it just didn't display a blank page...

feel free to copy and paste your comment as an answer here so I can give you the credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have at least one post (not a page) in your blog?

> i made a post and it worked. I don't know why it just didn't display a blank page

Technically, WordPress was doing what it was supposed to do - no posts were found, hence the 'Not Found' status!